# Is there a CDN for backbone.marionette?

Tags: cdn

[Getting started with Backbone and Marionette](http://davidsulc.com/blog/2012/05/06/tutorial-a-full-backbone-marionette-application-part-1/), I was about to copy the file at `https://github.com/marionettejs/backbone.marionette/blob/master/lib/backbone.marionette.js` to my local server, but wondered if there was a CDN version of it.

For Underscore and Backbone dev, I'm including these two files, respectively:

http://documentcloud.github.com/underscore/underscore-min.js

http://documentcloud.github.com/backbone/backbone-min.js

Is there a similar URL for backbone.marrionette.js?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Github is not a CDN.  Don't use it like that.   Also, don't include the `HTTP://` when using a CDN domain or else on SSL pages you will get security errors.

You could simply use `src="//documentcloud.github.com/backbone/backbone-min.js"` which will be HTTP on HTTP requests and HTTPS on SSL requests.

Now as for CDN, take a look at CloudFlare 
[CDNJS.com](http://cdnjs.com/).  Its not Akamai, but it's free.

Here is a link to the framework you were interested in 
//cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/backbone.marionette/0.10.2/backbone.marionette.min.js

Answer (score 2):

Marionette is available on http://www.cdnjs.com search for it or just use `//cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/backbone.marionette/0.10.2/backbone.marionette.min.js`